# How to pass packets between two network interfaces through manually written filter?

Tags: routes, iptables

I have two physical network adapters on the Linux machine: eth0 and eth1. eth0 is for users and eth1 has outer Network access. 
Then I can do `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE` and users can connect to Network behind the NAT.

What I want to do: manually capture packets from eth0, inspect it (may be making some changes, dump etc.) and write back to eth1. Something like this:

```
         +-------------------------------------+
         |            / my program \           |
user --- |eth0 ----- |tap0 --- tap1| ----- eth1| --- Network
         +-------------------------------------+
```

I've written a program, that opens tap0 and tap1, simply read from tap0 and write to tap1 and vice versa (no packet changes for now):

```
tap0 192.168.100.1
tap1 192.168.200.1
```

Then:

```
ip route add <outer network IP> via 192.168.100.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tap0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also tried;

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`)
```

I see ARP requests incoming on tap0, and outgoing from tap1 (repeated by my program), but nothing more.

**How to make this packets to go to eth1? How to make all incoming packets on eth0 to go through my filter and to outer network (not only specific address)?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution for my problem: using NFQUEUE!

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

An example of dealing with a queue from application is [here](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/598-linux-mitm-nfqueue)